# Flash upload request automatic retry via HTTPS on 407 error

Tags: flash, authentication, upload

We are using a flash uploader in our ASP.NET application which works fine for most of our clients. However for some with Proxy server setup in  their organisation the upload fails intermittently resulting a crash. On investigating the issue I found this is due to the "407 Authentication Required" request initiated by the Proxy server. When we tried switching the whole website running under HTTPS this issue seems to be resolved but that started some other 500 errors throughout the applications. As a temporary fix I enabled the HTTPS only for the upload component leaving the site running under HTTP. This seems to resolve the issue now.

But as I am looking forward for a permanent fix, I am thinking of handling the proxy exception (407) in my Flash code and try to reissue it with a HTTPS call (Not sure whether this is permitted though). When I tried to handle the HTTPStatusEvent I got the exception correctly using fiddler, but no further request goes eventhough I force a upload request via HTTPS. Please find the code sample below which I am doing (ActionScript Flex 3)

> _file.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS ,OnHttpError);
>
> private function OnHttpError(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void{
>               if (event.status==407){
>                   Upload(true);
>               }
>               else{
>                   HandleExceptions("Http Error: ",event.status,"" );
>               }
>               this.dispatchEvent(event);
>           }
>   public function Upload(enableHttps:Boolean=false):void{
>               _uploading = true;
>               _bytesUploaded = 0;

```
        var uploadURLTemp:String = _uploadUrl;
        if(enableHttps==true){
            uploadURLTemp = uploadURLTemp.replace("http://","https://");

        }
        _file.upload(new URLRequest(uploadURLTemp));


    }
```

The _file object is a FileReference object and _uploadURL is the upload handler url in the server. I am not sure whether I am permitted to do this or is there any a better way to handle this.

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated

Regards

Sherin

Answer (score 0):

As far as the errors you are experiencing, I agree that this sounds like a back-end problem rather than a Flash problem.

Generally speaking, the most difficult part about performing HTTPS calls in flash is setting up and loading the crossdomain.xml policy. If these https calls you are making are working then I am assuming you have everything properly configured.

However, there are a number of things to take into consideration here if you have not already:

- Contacting a server in HTTPS when the .SWF has been loaded via HTTP may require a crossdomain.xml
- If your secured content is being hosted on a subdomain such as secure.mywebsite.com the SWF may not have proper permissions *(lack of or incorrectly configured crossdomain.xml)* to access www.mywebsite.com or vice-versa.

> But as I am looking forward for a permanent fix, I am thinking of handling the proxy exception (407) in my Flash code and try to reissue it with a HTTPS call (Not sure whether this is permitted though).

As long as a valid and properly configured crossdomain.xml file has been loaded by the SWF, you can call or re-call http, https, or even socket connections all you want.

I only wonder that since HTTP seems to be unstable for you, **it is likely easier to simply use https until you resolve your proxy issues.**

Comment: Thanks for that. But my issue is not that I cannot contact the server via HTTPS. I am able to do that without any issue (if the _uploadUrl is set with https when the page is loaded). The issue I have is I set the _uploadUrl in HTTP protocol and try to reissue in HTTPS automatically when 407 exception happens. In this instance it simply does not do anything.(Just gives up). Hope it is clear now